# Exception: Extension function glGenBuffers not supported SharpGL

Tags: c#, wpf, opengl, sharpgl

При использовании glGenuffers() выдаёт ошибку.
`Exception: Extension function glGenBuffers not supported`

В контроле стоит RenderContextType FBO.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        uint[] vao = new uint[] {1};
        GLControl.OpenGL.GenBuffers(0, vao);
    }
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Ну а код покажите то какой у вас.

Comment: ```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            uint[] vao = new uint[] {1};
            GLControl.OpenGL.GenBuffers(0, vao);
        }
    }
``` вот весь код. В WinForms была точно такая же ошибка но она решалась сменой контекста на FBO

Comment: Я вставил код из комментария в пост, на будущее - делайте так же.

Comment: Быть может здесь есть что-то полезное https://stackoverflow.com/a/6425443/12888024